# Turn for-loop code into multi-threading code with max number of threads

Tags: python, multithreading, function, for-loop

**Background:** I'm trying to do 100's of dymola simulations with the python-dymola interface. I managed to run them in a for-loop. Now I want them to run while multi-threading so I can run multiple models parallel (which will be much faster). Since probably nobody uses the interface, I wrote some simple code that also shows my problem:

**1: Turn a for-loop into a definition that is run into another for-loop BUT both the def and the for-loop share the same variable 'i'.**

**2: Turn a for-loop into a definition and use multi-threading to execute it. A for-loop runs the command one by one. I want to run them parallel with a maximum of x threads at the same time. The result should be the same as when executing the for-loop**

Example-code:

```
import os

nSim = 100
ndig='{:01d}'

for i in range(nSim):
    os.makedirs(str(ndig.format(i)))
```

Note that the name of the created directories are just the numbers from the for-loop (this is important). Now instead of using the for-loop, I would love to create the directories with multi-threading (*note: probably not interesting for this short code but when calling and executing 100's of simulation models it definitely is interesting to use multi-threading*).

So I started with something simple I thought, turning the for-loop into a function that then is run inside another for-loop and hoped to have the same result as with the for-loop code above but got this error: 
**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'**
(note: I just started with this, because I did not use the def-statement before and the thread package is also new. After this I would evolve towards the multi-threading.)

**1:**

```
import os

nSim = 100
ndig='{:01d}'

def simulation(i):
    os.makedirs(str(ndig.format(i)))

for i in range(nSim):
    simulation(i=i).start
```

After that failed, I tried to evolve to multi-threading (converting the for-loop into something that does the same but with multi-threading and by that running the code parallel instead of one by one and with a maximum number of threads):

**2:**

```
import os
import threading


nSim = 100
ndig='{:01d}'

def simulation(i):
    os.makedirs(str(ndig.format(i)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    i in range(nSim)
    simulation_thread[i] = threading.Thread(target=simulation(i=i))
    simulation_thread[i].daemon = True
    simulation_thread[i].start()
```

Unfortunately that attempt failed as well and now I got the error:
**NameError: name 'i' is not defined**

Does anybody has suggestions for issues 1 or 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both examples are incomplete.  Here's a complete example.  Note that `target` gets passed the name of the function `target=simulation` and a tuple of its arguments `args=(i,)`.  Don't call the function `target=simulation(i=i)` because that just passes the result of the function, which is equivalent to `target=None` in this case.

```
import threading

nSim = 100

def simulation(i):
    print(f'{threading.current_thread().name}: {i}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=simulation,args=(i,)) for i in range(nSim)]
    for t in threads:
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

Output:

```
Thread-1: 0
Thread-2: 1
Thread-3: 2
 .
 .
Thread-98: 97
Thread-99: 98
Thread-100: 99
```

Note you usually don't want more threads that CPUs, which you can get from `multiprocessing.cpu_count()`.  You can use create a thread pool and use `queue.Queue` to post work that the threads execute.  An example is in the [Python Queue documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.join).

Comment: I'm sorry but when I run that bit of code, I get a syntax error because of the 'f' in the print statement under def simulation(i). Is this a Python2/Python3 thing..? (I'm using Python3)
When I delete that 'f' or replace it by a string-statement the code runs but I just get 100 times '{threading.current_thread().name}: {i}', so not the output you stated above ;-)

{threading.current_thread().name}: {i}
{threading.current_thread().name}: {i}
{threading.current_thread().name}: {i}
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
{threading.current_thread().name}: {i}
{threading.current_thread().name}: {i}

Comment: @Matthi9000 Python 3.6 added f-strings.  `print('{}: {}'.format(threading.current_thread().name,i))` is the old way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Cannot call .start like this

   ```
   simulation(i=i).start
   ```

   on an non-threading object. Also, you have to import the module as well
2. It seems like you forgot to add 'for' and indent the code in your loop

   ```
   i in range(nSim)
   simulation_thread[i] = threading.Thread(target=simulation(i=i))
   simulation_thread[i].daemon = True
   simulation_thread[i].start()
   ```

   to

   ```
   for i in range(nSim):
       simulation_thread[i] = threading.Thread(target=simulation(i=i))
       simulation_thread[i].daemon = True
       simulation_thread[i].start()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have max number of thread in a pool, and to run all items in the queue. We can continue @mark-tolonen answer and do like this:

```
import threading
import queue
import time

def main():
    size_of_threads_pool = 10
    num_of_tasks = 30
    task_seconds = 1
    
    q = queue.Queue()

    def worker():
        while True:
            item = q.get()
            print(my_st)
            print(f'{threading.current_thread().name}: Working on {item}')
            time.sleep(task_seconds)
            print(f'Finished {item}')
            q.task_done()

    my_st = "MY string"
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=worker, daemon=True) for i in range(size_of_threads_pool)]
    for t in threads:
        t.start()


    # send the tasks requests to the worker
    for item in range(num_of_tasks):
        q.put(item)

    # block until all tasks are done
    q.join()
    print('All work completed')

    # NO need this, as threads are while True, so never will stop..
    # for t in threads:
    #    t.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This will run 30 tasks of 1 second in each, using 10 threads.
So total time would be 3 seconds.

```
$ time python3 q_test.py 
...
All work completed

real  0m3.064s
user  0m0.033s
sys   0m0.016s
```

### EDIT: I found another higher-level interface for asynchronously executing callables.

Use [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#module-concurrent.futures), see the [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example) in the docs:

```
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']

# Retrieve a single page and report the URL and contents
def load_url(url, timeout):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
        return conn.read()

# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
        else:
            print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))
```

> Note the `max_workers=5` that will tell the max number of threads, and
> note the for loop `for url in URLS` that you can use.